# Package to get an estimate of the survival function with random effects?

Tags: r, package, survival-analysis, estimation, random-effects

I would like an estimation of the cumulative hazard in a function that includes random (and fixed) effects.
The estimation should be semi-parametric (estimation with splines, piecwise constant exponential, etc)

I tried the R package `frailtypack` but the `additivePenal` function does not work good (it does not converge with a strata term).

Does anyone have a suggestion of a R function to get estimates of the survival function (with a strata term) and random effects ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html might be of interest?

Comment: I haven't used it for a few years, but the `coxme` package is the first hit when I search for "survival random effects in r". Same maintainer as the `survival` package, which is promising.

Comment: @Gregor :'coxme' does not provide an estimation of the survival function... I already checked this package. Thanks !

Comment: @Rob: I found the `frailtyEM` package on the page Survival that might be appealing. Thanks :-)